# spark streaming application fails after a while: ERROR DiskBlockObjectWriter: Uncaught exception while reverting partial writes to file

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

Someone can give me some advice?

I have a spark streaming application(2.3.1) reading kafka data to run a aggregation function over a sliding 5 minute windows. The amount of data is about 2000 in 5 minutes. The configuration is：

```
 --deploy-mode cluster  --driver-memory  2g \
 --num-executors 5  --executor-memory  3g  \
 --executor-cores 2 --conf  "spark.default.parallelism=50"\
 --conf "spark.executor.memoryOverhead=2048"
```

The application fails after running a while (2 hours more or less) with the following executor log :

```
 ERROR DiskBlockObjectWriter: Uncaught exception while reverting partial writes to file /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/lvhuimin/appcache/application_1570760632834_15773/blockmgr-852d0f0f-9026-4c77-a37b-22ed94709c09/1c/temp_shuffle_a6818c3e-904f-494e-ac4d-af26b7380de0
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.truncate(FileChannelImpl.java:372)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter$$anonfun$revertPartialWritesAndClose$2.apply$mcV$sp(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1389)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.revertPartialWritesAndClose(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.stop(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:237)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here are some sample codes:

```
data_df.withWatermark("ts", "5 minutes")
    .groupBy(window($"ts", "5 minutes"), $"A",$"B", ... ,$"C")
    .agg(count($"user_id") as "dev_cnt", sum($"revenue") as "revenue")
    .select("window.start", "window.end","A", "B", ... ,"C")
    .writeStream
    .outputMode("update")
    .foreach(writer("table_name"))
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointDir)
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("20 seconds"))
    .start()

def writer(tablename: String): JDBCPostgreSink = {
    new JDBCPostgreSink()
}
```

Comment: Please share sample code

Comment: Yes, I have already added